# x509: cannot validate certificate for <<HOST IP>> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs - Hyperledger Fabric-CA

Tags: docker, ssl, openssl, hyperledger-fabric, tls1.2

I'm trying to enroll an intermediate certificate authority with its root certificate authority, I'm using TLS and the CAs run in separated docker containers using the fabric-ca images. If I send the CSR trough the docker network there are no problems, but if I try to send it trough my local network I have this problem: x509: cannot validate certificate for "HOST_IP" because it doesn't contain any IP SANs. I read that the reason for my problem, is that the TLS certificate(s) don't contain IP SANs (IP subject alternative names), this is a field in the TLS certificate that basically says: "The certificate was issued to a host that its IP is: <1.2.3.4>". So, if that is the problem, how I could add this field to my certificate? and if not, what is the problem and how I could resolve it? Thanks and regards!

Comment: Sending the CSR through one network path or another does not change its content. Are you sure that when sending the CSR through the docker network, it contains a SAN? Anyway, SO is about programming, not system administration. May you find good answers on ServerFault.

Comment: I realized that it was just a silly mistake, I was mistakenly naming the csr hostname, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024158/peers-not-joining-channel-and-error-with-tls-connection-ip-sans-error) with a similar IP SANS issue. There is also detailed explanation of IP SANS issue in HLF [mailing List](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9697). Also make sure when you are using Fabric CA Client, to generate the certificates, use the server's hostname to request the same. for e.g. `fabric-ca-client enroll -d --enrollment.profile tls -c <client configuration file> -u https://admin:adminpw@<server hostname>:7054 --csr.hosts $PEER_HOST`. If IP address is given in URL TLS handshake will fail with `bad TLS certificate` error on the server side and 'certificate does not contain IP SANS' error on the client side as the ca-cert.pem used to perform the handshake with the server contains hostname and not the IP address.